# How to investigate excessive java garbage collection

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Tomcat instance which is exhibiting the following behaviour:

- Accept a single http incoming request.
- Issue one request to a backend server and get back about 400kb of XML.
- Pass through this XML and transform it into about 400kb of JSON.
- Return the JSON response.

The problem is that in the course of handling the 400k request my webapp generates about 100mb of garbage which fills up the Eden space and triggers a young generation collection.

I have tried to use the built in java hprof functionality to do allocation sites profiling but Tomcat didn't seem to start up properly with that in place. It is possible that I was just a bit impatient as I imagine memory allocation profiling has a high overhead and therefore tomcat startup might take a long time

What are the best tools to use to do java memory profiling of very young objects/garbage? I can't use heap dumps because the objects I'm interested in are garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the profiler in jvisualvm in the JDK to do memory profiling.

Also have a look at Templates to cache the XSLT transformer.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Templates.html

Comment: Jvisualvm profiling is difficult as my tomcat server runs on linux and I would rather avoid the ovehead of getting it running on windows where I do my development or installing a gui Linux box.

Comment: Install the corresponding JDK on the Linuxbox, and redirect jvisualvm to use an X11 server running on your windows box.  Xming directly on the machine, or Knoppix running in a vmware session, works very nicely.

Comment: Also note that if you add the appropriate voodoo to the Tomcat JVM invocation, jvisualvm can connect from your Windowsbox without further adieu.

Comment: Take a look at how to enable remote JMX monitoring http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html#remote. In Tomcat, just place the arguments in bin/setenv.sh (i.e. `export CATALINA_OPTS='com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345'` etc)

Comment: I think redirecting x is likely to be the best bet. As far as I'm aware visualvm can connect remotely but cannot do remote memory profiling.

Comment: In fact the best solution looks like the Netbeans Profiler which supports remote profiling of Tomcat which is exactly what I want. I'll try this out tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

As to the actual problem: XML parsing can be very memory hogging when using a DOM based parser. Consider using a [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) or [binary XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_XML) based parser ([VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/) is a Java API based on that).

Actually, if the XML->JSON mapping is pure 1:1, then you can also consider to just read the XML and write the JSON realtime line by line using a little stack.

---

Back to the question: I suggest to use [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) for this. You can find [here](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/monitoring-tomcat-with-java-visualvm) a blog article how to get it to work with Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get heap dumps to work anyway by debugging the app, placing breakpoints at key points of the code and creating a heap dump while the app is paused at each breakpoint.

Comment: I suspect the garbage is short lived in which case it would be extremely tough to spot which bits if memory are newly allocated. I ideally want something like visual vm memory profiling which I can run again my tomcat process on my Linux server.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [LambdaProbe](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/index.htm), which is a profiler for Tomcat.
It supports the following:

**Overview**

**Lambda Probe (formerly Tomcat Probe) is a self sufficient web application, which helps to visualize various parameters of Apache Tomcat instance in real time. Lambda Probe is designed to work specifically with Tomcat so it is able to access far more information that is normally available to JMX agents. Here is a list of features available through Lambda Probe:**

- New! Comprehensive JVM memory usage
  monitor.
- JBoss compatibility
- Display of deployed applications,
  their status, session count, session
  object count, context object count,
  datasource usage etc.
- Start, stop, restart, deploy and
  updeploy of applications
- Ability to view deployed JSP files
- Ability to compile all or selected
  JSP files at any time.
- Ability to pre-compile JSP files on
  application deployment.
- New! Ability to view auto-generated
  JSP servlets
- Display of list of sessions for a
  particular application
- Display of session attributes and
  their values for a particular
  application. Ability to remove
  session attributes.
- Ability to view application context
  attributes and their values.
- Ability to expire selected sessions
- Graphical display of datasource
  details including maximum number of
  connections, number of busy
  connections and configuration details
- New! Ability to group datasource
  properties by URL to help visualizing
  impact on the databases
- Ability to reset data sources in case
  of applications leaking connection
- Display of system information
  including System.properties, memory
  usage bar and OS details
- Display of JK connector status
  including the list of requests
  pending execution
- Real-time connector usage charts and
  statistics.
- Real-time cluster monitoring and
  clulster traffic charts
- New! Real time OS memory usage, swap
  usage and CPU utilisation monitoring
- Ability to show information about log
  files and download selected files
- Ability to tail log files in real
  time from a browser.
- Ability to interrupt execution of
  "hang" requests without server
  restart
- New! Ability to restart Tomcat/JVM
  via Java Serview Wrapper.
- Availability "Quick check"
- Support for DBCP, C3P0 and Oracle
  datasources
- Support for Tomcat 5.0.x and 5.5.x
- Support for Java 1.4 and Java 1.5

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mchr3k/org.inmemprofiler/wiki (http://mchr3k.github.io/org.inmemprofiler/)

InMemProfiler can be used to identify which objects are collected after a very short time.